# Java compiled with gcj using javax.comm api. Possible?

Tags: java, javax.comm

I have a java program that I'm required to compile into a Linux native program using gcj-4.3.  This program requires serial port access.  The javax.comm api provides serial port access but I'm not sure how to get my compiled java program to use it.

The target box has Java installed, but of course my compiled program isn't running in the JRE...so I'm not exactly sure how I can link in the comm.jar file or how that file can find the .properties file it requires.

I wonder if I can just compile the comm.jar allong with my .jar file and link the two object files together.  Can my code then reference the classes in comm.jar?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an GCJ expert but I have some suggestions (I'm not providing the syntax, this will require some exploration that I didn't perform):

- first, I think that you'll have to compile `comm.jar` into a (shared) library,
- then, you'll have to link your code against the library,
- finally, use the `GCJ_PROPERTIES` environment variable to pass properties to the program at invocation time.

The following pointers might be helpful to implement this:

- [GCJ---The GNU Compiler for Java](http://training.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2003.html) (great resources IMO, covers all the steps mentioned above)
- [GCJ – Getting Started](http://www.openstatic.org/?page_id=6) (more an intro but still nice)
- [Compile ActiveMQ with GCJ](http://activemq.apache.org/compile-activemq-with-gcj.html) (more use cases but I don't think they apply here)
- And of course, the [official documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcj/) :)